# Why is MTM attempting to load the wrong version of CodedUITestFramework DLL when I run a test case via Microsoft Test Manager?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, tfs, visual-studio-2013, microsoft-test-manager

**The Set Up**

I have TFS 2012, VS 2013 and Test Controller 2013 on my machine which runs Windows 8.1 x64

I have installed a Windows 7 x86 VM and on it I've installed VS 2012, VS 2013 and Test Controller 2013 (in that order). The VM is my test controller.

**The Issue**

When I run the test case on MTM I get the following message:

> Error adding test case [14] to test run: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Why is it trying to load version 11?

Comment: You cannot link a 2013 test controller to a 2012 server, you can the other way around. The TFS server governs the highest compatible version, in your case 2012.

Comment: @jessehouwing Oh right. Let me try replacing the 2013 controller with 2012.

Comment: @jessehouwing That indeed did work. Thanks! If you could put that as an answer rather than a comment I could mark it as the correct one. Thanks again.

Comment: Though it solved your problem, I see that I'm mistaking in my assertion. The documentation says that the 2013 test agent should be able to work with the TFS 2012 server. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn641202.aspx#TCM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the documentation mentions that the 2013 Test Agent should work with your TFS 2012 server, I've usually not mixed and matched agent versions and relied on the agent matching the TFS server version. It reduces these type of issues. I'm glad this was an option for you and that it also fixes your issue, though technically your original approach [should also have worked according to the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn641202.aspx#TCM).

Comment: Oh right. That's odd. Nevertheless thanks for the help!